# Car hire for driving from Bulgaria to Italy

Tags: car-rentals, bulgaria, age-limits, bologna

We want to rent a car in Varna, Bulgaria, drive to Bologna, Italy and leave the car there. One driver is in the age range 30-65 and the other 69. Both have full licences.

Is this is possible?

---

(Gayot's edit, pasting comment into question body)

I am 59 and have a full driving licence. My husband is 69 and has a full driving licence. I would leave the car back to the hire company. My question is does anyone know car hire companies that would allow us to rent a car to complete this journey?

Comment: I am 59 and have a full driving licence. My husband is 69 and has a full driving licence. I would leave the car back to the hire company. My question is does anyone know car hire companies that would allow us to rent a car to complete this journey? Thanks

Comment: Great itinerary. It will take you through Melania territory. But they like to keep the pick-up and drop-off locations the same and locating a trading  company like that via commercial channels will be difficult. I recommend private.

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible to hire a car in Bulgaria with the age of 59 and 69?

> Yes, it is possible. Rental car age limits in Bulgaria are stricter 
>   than other countries, with most suppliers requiring a minimum age of 
>   21 and maximum age of 70.
>
> Answer is from [Rental Car Age
>   Requirement](http://www.autoeurope.com/go/travel-tips/rental-car-age-requirements/):
>
> [image]

Any hire companies that would allow us to rent a car to complete this
 journey?

Actually this is opinion based question. Some rental car companies are willing to provide you a car, but also bear in mind that charges are extremely high if you plan to hire a car in Varna (Bulgaria) and drop off at Bologna (Italy). You have to search car rental by your own.

Maybe this could help finding a good deal: http://www.priceline.com/landing/cars.htm?&lrdr=secure

Just now I managed to book a car from Varna (Bulgria) to Bologna (Italy) with Budget car reference number 118-956-274-37

[image]

Comment: The surcharge for an international one-way car rental is not so extremely high when you consider that an employee most likely is required to drive the car back to the origin country.

Comment: +1 I don't know why the Priceline site didn't work for me but I was able to book similar on the Budget site.  A word of warning: it shows you a low price, but the T&C state there is a one-way surcharge, and you have to contact the branch to find out the details.  This is not at all obvious unless you read the fine print.